# simple way to run background.js file when a button on popup.html is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, background, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to run a function in my background.js file when I click a button on my popup.html file, I have tried a bunch of examples online and so far none of them have worked for me.

Here is what Ive tried:

```
$(".start-btn").click(function() {

    var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#select-task").val());

    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var autobuy = $(checkbox).prop('checked');
    var delay = $("#checkout-ms").val();
    var count = localStorage.getItem('count');


    chrome.storage.sync.set({'task': task.cells, 'count': count}, function() {

    });

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'autobuy': autobuy, 'delay': delay}, function() {
    });

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'run': true);
```

then in the background.js file tried to do this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
  if(!message.run) return;

  finder();
});

function finder() {
    //pulling json info and opening url loop
});
```

I want to chrome.storage.sync.get all my things that I saved in my popup.js file then run the function.. I have tried a bunch of solutions and so far none of them have worked for me...

Thank you for helping me in advance <3!

Comment: Wht is `finder` supposed to do? Pull the values of `task`, `count`, `autoby` and `delay` from the storage?

Comment: it uses task and count @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: Why not send'em over as part of the message? `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ run: true, task: ..., count: ... });`

Comment: BTW the problem you're facing is because of the asynchronous nature of `chrome.storage.sync.set`. That function doesn't do its job right away, so `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` actually happens before anything is set on the storage.

Comment: Send'em over to the background, run the save query there and use whatever you want, I guess.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ok i tried sending them all as a message, and when I clicked the button nothing showed up in the console

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Could you post a working example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`popup.js`:**

Accumulate the data then send it over to the background:

```
$(".start-btn").click(function() {

    var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#select-task").val());

    var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var autobuy = $(checkbox).prop('checked');
    var delay = $("#checkout-ms").val();
    var count = localStorage.getItem('count');

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ run: true, data: {
        task: task.cells,
        count,
        autobuy,
        delay
    } });
}
```

**`background.js`:**

Retrieve the data sent over from the popup, store it and use it:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if(!message.run) return;

    var data = message.data;
    chrome.storage.sync.set(data, function() { /* ... */ });
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: what do I put between the  { /* ... */}  ??

Comment: Becuase right now when I press the button nothing shows up in the console

Comment: @developer12 The background script has a separate console. [**You'll have to open that console first**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10257301/9867451) to see the logs. The `/* ... */` are the code of the callback of `chrome.storage.sync.set`, you put code there to check if setting the storage has succeded or not. Read more about it in chrome extension docs!